# Is there any destroy hook for pipes in angular2 (same as for components)?

Tags: angular, observable

After investigating for several days(!?!) for a huge memory leakage of my current Angular2 application, I came up with the new discovery:

Apparently, an async pipe, which was heavily used throughout the application, was subscribing for an observable, but was never released (unsubscribed) when component and pipes where cleaned-up.

It accumulated to a number of ~11,000 observers for a single observable with very few user actions (which eventually caused the app to crash).

I need to unsubscribe the observable, and in order to do that I need a hook for destruction, similar to ngOnDestroy, but for pipes.

Is there any such hook, or if not, how would you suggest to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you take a look at the [async pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) code, you can see that they are using `ngOnDestroy` just like how would you do it in a directive.

snippet from `AsyncPipe` code:

```
@Pipe({name: 'async', pure: false})
@Injectable()
export class AsyncPipe implements OnDestroy {
  ...

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (isPresent(this._subscription)) {
      this._dispose();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The key is using: `pure:false`,

From [OnDestroy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnDestroy-class.html)

> To create a stateful Pipe, you should implement this interface and set the pure parameter to false in the PipeMetadata.
>
> A stateful pipe may produce different output, given the same input. It is likely that a stateful pipe may contain state that should be cleaned up when a binding is destroyed. For example, a subscription to a stream of data may need to be disposed, or an interval may need to be cleared.

Comment: That could have been nice if it worked, but debugging ngOnDestroy indicates that pipe own't ever enter this method on destruction (or ever).
Did you see it working yourself?

Comment: @ChenEshchar, I just created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HXHTKj6IwBf2iHdHgoyx?p=preview) to test it and it works. Click the button to show/hide the component and watch the console.

Comment: I see your plunk and I see the docs but for me, it won't enter the ngOnDestroy. It might be the case since it's...not released for GC.
I will investigate a little bit further, but in the meantime, thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChenEshchar If you add your pipe code to your question, I might be able to see where you went wrong.

Comment: I don't know from which Angular version, but onDestroy can be used even with pure pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 16 we have [takeUntilDestroyed](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed) pipe. It must be used either in constructor or by passing [DestroyRef](https://angular.io/api/core/DestroyRef). The second case also allows us to react to a destruction of some other component.

```
export class DemoComponent {
  protected destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fooObservable.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe((value) => {
      ...do something
    });
  }
}
```